# CONCAT [Name] [Surname] to [FullName] in the same table using INSERT INTO SELECT statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `UK_bank_customers` with columns

```
[customer ID], ..., [Name], [Surname], ..., [Age], ...etc.
```

I want to add a new column to that table - `[Full_Name]` which can be calculated by concatenating `[Name]` and `[Surname]`.

Please suggest some ways to do that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHqqF.png)

The output table to contain this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHbSq.png)

Comment: `ALTER TABLE UK_bank_customers ADD Full_Name AS CONCAT(Name, ' ', Surname)`

Comment: My question would be what is the reason for this?  If you want it viewed/etc you can concat them when you select it, or have the UI concat them.  Doing it like this in the DB takes up space and if name or surname are updated, you have to update this new column instead of just concat them on select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add a computed column to your table - just do this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.UK_bank_customers 
    ADD Full_Name AS CONCAT(Name, ' ', Surname) PERSISTED;
```

You now have a `Full_Name` column that will always contain the concatenation of your `Name` and `Surname` - separated by a space.

But the question really is: **why** do you need this? You can always easily achieve the same goal doing this `CONCAT` operation when you select data from the table - in a view, or in an ad-hoc SQL statement. So why do you feel the need to **store** that concatenated data??

Comment: what do we use PERSISTED?

Comment: What if i wanted to add this new column Full_Name to a specific position in the UK_bank_customers table?

Comment: @RohanSrivastva: then the values is actually physically stored in the database table - which also means it doesn't have to be re-computed every time you access that column. Benefit is better performance

Comment: Relational tables don't have *specific locations* - they are **inherently** an unordered bag of data. If you need to return the `Full_Name` at a "specific location" - define the proper sequence of columns in your `SELECT (list-of-columns)` part of the query

Comment: please provide me your email address at least for quick doubt clearing

Comment: No way - I work a fulltime job, I do not have the time (and energy) to do one-on-one consulting on the side, for free. If you have questions - **ask them HERE!** - that's what this site is for!!